# How to include header only directory to run ns-3?

Tags: ns-3, waf

I'm working on ns-3 to include header files to my own module.
I've tried to type commands on ./waf command and wscript file, but it doesn't work. Below I listed the commands that I've tried.

In wscript file,

```py
conf.env.append_value('CXXFLAGS', ['-I/path/to/directory'])
conf.env.append_value('INCLUDES', '/path/to/directory')
```

In ./waf command,

```
./waf --run file_name --includedir /path/to/directory

./waf --run file_name --includedir/path/to/directory
```

And in my script, I just put `#include "headerfile.h"` which is in the directory.

Thank you.

Comment: And what exactly does not work? Adding a include directory to `CXXFLAGS` wrong anyway. `conf.env.append_value('INCLUDES', '/path/to/directory')` this is generally correct. Is `path/to/directory` a relative or absolute path?

Comment: @user69453 That path is absolute, and I tried to use those command each as well as together. I feel that configuration of ns-3 and waf is difficult for me..

Comment: Can show the command line generated by waf when you get the compile error?